# C++ Double Linked List, should I delete the nodes after dynamically allocating them?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, linked-list

```
 void addEnd(T data) {
    if (head == NULL) {
      Node<T> *temp = new Node<T>(data);
      head = temp;
      tail = temp;
      temp = NULL;
      delete temp;
      ++size;
    } else {
      Node<T> *temp = new Node<T>(data);
      tail->LinkToNext(temp);
      temp->LinkToPrev(tail);
      tail = temp;
      temp = NULL;
      delete temp;
      ++size;
    }
  }
```

In the addEnd function above, should I delete temp after I used it to allocate new Node on heap because it may cause memory leak or it doesn't matter.

Comment: ***should I delete the nodes after dynamically allocating them?*** Certainly not. You delete them when you no longer want the node not before that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must not delete the newly created node in the `addEnd` function because it will be used later. The nodes should be deleted when the list is thrown away. (maybe in the destructor and/or something like `clear()` function).

Also note that the `delete temp;` in your code is meaningless (no gain, no harm) because `temp` is set to `NULL` before that and `delete NULL;` is defined to do nothing.

The variable `temp` itself is typically allocated on the stack and automatically deleted on returning from the function, so you need not delete it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't delete variables, you delete memory. In your code above `temp` is `NULL` which means deleting it does nothing, so don't bother.